# What is the formalism for calculating the vacuum energy density from the observed data of the expansion of the universe?

Tags: space-expansion, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Wikipedia states [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem#Estimated_values) the calculated effective vacuum energy density value of free space from the observed and collected cosmological constant data of the 2015 Planck telescope satellite mission. But there is no clear presentation of the maths used to calculate this value?

Can you point me to a specific reference or give here the basic equations used?

Comment: [The calculation is described here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209).